# Use String for photo Uri?

Tags: android, string, file, uri, android-file

I need to create a new file name/Uri for every picture taken using my app. The first picture they take will be "/sdcard/mirror1.jpg" then the next picture taken will be "mirror2.jpg" and so on. Here's my code so far:

```
 capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int count = 1;
            count++;

            String fileName = new String("/sdcard/mirror" + count + ".jpg");

            File thing = new File(fileName);
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(thing));
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Will this work? I can add any extra code/details you need.

Comment: Well if you've already written all the code... why don't you try it?

Comment: One thing you should change is the String "/sdcard" should be replaced by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() so that it works on all devices

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the "count" int outside of the onClickListener otherwise it will always contain the value "2" as it will be instanced again and again on each click.

You will also want to record the last use of the number when the application closes otherwise you will risk overwriting the images.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that count will always be reset to 1 on each click (because you declare and instantiate it inside the onClickListener).

And even if you fix that, when you close your app or activity you would lose progress.

So you should store the value of count somewhere.

The best way to do this is use the Shared Preferences.

So your code should look something like this

```
capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //read count from Shared Preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YourPrefName", 0);
        int count = settings.getInt("imageCount", 1);

        String fileName = new String("/sdcard/mirror" + count + ".jpg");

        File thing = new File(fileName);
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(thing));
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Instead of incrementing count here, we check if a photo was successfully taken. We do that in onActivityResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YourPrefName", 0);
        int count = settings.getInt("imageCount", 1);
        ++count;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("imageCount", count);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```